# Modified Duration as interest risk

Tags: bond, bond-yields, duration

I am new to bond pricing and I am studying the sensitivity measures of a bond (with discrete compounding) and even though I understand the mathematical concepts of modified duration and convexity adjustment since the first is the tangent line of the price-yield curve (1st derivative) and the second is the 2nd derivative. But I want to present you a toy example in order to understand my difficulty that I face in interpretation of these measures.

Let's say that we have a bond with annual coupons $c =40$ and 10 years of maturity $n=10$ ,principal of face value $P_p=1000$ and interest rate $y = 0.08$.

Pricing the bond :

$$\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{ c}{(1+y)} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^2} +\frac{ c}{(1+y)^3}+ \dots + \frac{ c+P_p}{(1+y)^n}\\
&= \frac cy \left[1-(1+y)^{-n}\right] + P_p(1+y)^{-n}\\
&= \frac{40}{0.08}\left(1-1.08^{-10}\right) + 1000\cdot 1.08^{-10}\\
&\approx 268.4033 + 463.1935\\
&\approx 731.5967
\end{align*}$$

The Macaulay duration is $D_{Mac} = 8.1184$ and the Modified duration $D_{m}=7.5171$.

The modified duration is expressed in years. But it is also a sensitivity measure of the bond and this comes from that if there is a change on interest rates of 0.01% the price of the bond will change (increase or  decrease according to the sign) by $0.01 \times 7.5171 = 7.51\%$.
The convexity adjustment is $C_{adj} = 57.691\%$.

And here are my questions:

**1)** This percentage (7.51%) is the risk of the bond ?  Can i say for example that  this bond with these characteristics has a risk of $7.51\%$?

**2)** Is the interest rate risk ?

**3)** What is the interpretation of the value $57.691\%$ in the convexity adjustment?

Comment: This percentage (7.51%) multiplied by the market value of the bond position, is the risk of the bond position, specifically the DV01. So for example if you have 1 million dollars worth of this bond the risk (i.e the DV01) is 75,171 dollars.

Comment: I.e the risk of the bond.